# Arrange records in such a way that D category always comes first then E & F and it will be in the ratio of 1:1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my query result:-

```
0117491646420160812000000  D   0
0012980013220160911114106  D   0
0020876513320160503000000  E   1
0090022202120161227000000  E   1
0010557700720180504000000  F   2
0020254719320180518000000  F   2
```

What I want :-

```
0117491646420160812000000  D   0
0012980013220160911114106  D   0
0020876513320160503000000  E   1
0010557700720180504000000  F   2
0090022202120161227000000  E   1
0020254719320180518000000  F   2
```

I have to arrange my records according to this way that D always comes first what so ever,but in E and F category it comes in the ratio of 1:1 that means E F E F or in alternate way after D.

SQL Query-

```
SELECT m.allocationID,
       mt.CatId,
       mt.CatSName,
       r.officerName,
       r.desgName,
       r.grade,
       r.cellNo,
       CASE
           WHEN mt.CatSName = 'D' THEN 0
           WHEN mt.CatSName = 'E' THEN 1
           ELSE 2
       END AS ord
FROM msttransaction m,
     msttemp mt,
     regusers r
WHERE (m.isPending='Y'
       AND m.statusR='Approve'
       AND m.iscancelled='No'
       AND m.allocationID IN
         (SELECT mt.AllocationId
          FROM msttemp
          WHERE mt.quarterId='082505012')
       AND SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId, 1, 11)=r.pfNpsNo)
  OR (m.isPending='N'
      AND m.type='Transit'
      AND m.statusR='Approve'
      AND m.iscancelled='No'
      AND m.allocationID IN
        (SELECT mt.AllocationId
         FROM msttemp
         WHERE mt.quarterId='082505012')
      AND SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId, 1, 11)=r.pfNpsNo)
ORDER BY ord,
         SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId, -14)
```

Note i do not show some field in my example.

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
    ORDER BY FIELD(ord, 'D' , 'E', 'F'), SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId, -14)
```

Comment: How i am not good in mysql please help me by editing in query

Comment: just change  `ORDER BY ord,SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId, -14)` with  `ORDER BY  field(ord, 'D' , 'E', 'F'), SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId, -14)`  .. seems not difficult to me ..

Comment: It will order them by D, E and F.

Comment: yes but i want E and F in alternate way after D which is on higher priority

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you can do:

```
order by (ord = 'D') DESC,  -- d first
         row_number() over (partition by ord order by ord)
```

To do this in earlier versions is much trickier, requiring variables.

Comment: please help me to write this query in my existing query,i am new in mysql and php

Comment: i have mysql 5 version,please help me this problem by using session variables